# zOS DB2 connection string in PHP - from Bluemix to zOS

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud, zos, secure-gateway

I have a sample connection string from DashDB (DB2) on cloud that worked when I connected from Bluemix (A PHP cloud foundry app) to a cloud based DB2.

Now I would like to connect to a zOS DB2 DB using a Secure Gateway. I have the SG already set up and I have SG hostname and port also.

Here is the connection string preparation **using the sample from DashDB and adding the Secure Gatway hostname and port number** and my pw and my userID for this zOS DB2 database:

```
        $database = "EU***DB2*";        
        $hostname = "cio-sg-02.integration.ibmcloud.com";  
        $user     = "**myuserID**";   
        $password = "**myPW**";   
        $port     = **portfromSecureGatway**;          
        $ssl_port = **portfromSecureGatway**;
```

Here is the connection string build up (also from the DashDB sample..)

```
$driver  = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};";
        $dsn     = "DATABASE=$database; " .
                   "HOSTNAME=$hostname;" .
                   "PORT=$port; " .
                   "PROTOCOL=TCPIP; " .
                   "UID=$user;" .
                   "PWD=$password;";
        $ssl_dsn = "DATABASE=$database; " .
                   "HOSTNAME=$hostname;" .
                   "PORT=$ssl_port; " .
                   "PROTOCOL=TCPIP; " .
                   "UID=$user;" .
                   "PWD=$password;" .
                   "SECURITY=SSL;";
        $conn_string = $driver . $dsn;     # Non-SSL
        //$conn_string = $driver . $ssl_dsn; # SSL
```

Am I using the right driver for zOS/DB2?

and here is the connection command in PHP:

```
$connection = db2_connect($conn_string,$user,$password);
```

I opened a ticket for Secure Gateways Support team because I get **SQL30081N** error message with various setups (based on if I connect using SG Desktop Client - its running, - its not running, I'm using hosted SG Client.. and if I don't use SG and try to connect directly to zOS from my desktop (that case I receive license error as I don't have the zOS license file set up yet.)

Is it possible that the missing license causing the SQL30081N error too?

Support tells that I have an application error. Is it possible that I'm using the wrong connection string?

Comment: Static part of the SQL30081N error for each scenario I try: Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication API being used: "SOCKETS" SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30081

Comment: SG with SG Desktop Client turned ON - Communication function detecting the error: "recv". Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".

Comment: SG with SG Desktop Client turned OFF - Communication function detecting the error: "connect". Protocol specific error code(s): "111", "*", "*".

Comment: SG with SG COUD Client - Communication function detecting the error: "recv". Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0"

Comment: Are you following "Scenario-2" on page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_php.html

Comment: that worked for DashDB. I could connect to DashDB on cloud. But now I would like to connect to a zOS/DB2 (bluezone) DB...

Comment: but yes.. I'm using the code that is shown on the link you sent.

Comment: The SQLCODE -30081 reason code has <rc1><rc2><rc3>. The <rc3> "0" means remote side terminated the connection (either SG or Z/OS), and "111" means connection-refused. Does the SG allow both unencrypted and encrypted connections? If so, does the symptom change when using unencrypted versus encrypted connections?  Did you get the cert for your Z/OS hostname and use it?

Comment: SQLCODE -30081 reason code has <rc1><rc2><rc3> - when rc1 = "111" is on that case when I turn down the Secure Gatways Client side... for testing purposes.. to check if the error code changes in case I turn off a part of the SG.

Comment: No I did not get certification for Z/OS hostanem, and I don't use it... will need to look into this how to get one.

Comment: Also I did not check for encryption.. thx for these two directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL30081N did not found any suggestion on the web yet.. but I received this error message because of Secure Gatway ACL file content. ... fixed it and it works now.